# Conky Guides (links)

Tags: customization, appearance, conky

I want to take a stab at creating my own layouts for conky, but I'm having trouble finding any recent guides.

If you know of any, I would be grateful if you could post some links.

Comment: When I dove into conky, all I did was look over the documentation (http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) and wiki(http://wiki.conky.be/index.php?title=Conky_Wiki). It's syntax is very easy to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started with this [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5067341/customize-conky-for-ambient-linux-productivity) to set me up which led me to this [ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865) with lots of config files to help customize everything.

This [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3aubuntuforums.org+%22%5ball+variants%22+conky&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu%3aen-US%3aunofficial) helps to find some more scripts ready.

Comment: Lifehacker has a lot of conky coverage, actually: http://lifehacker.com/search/conky/

Answer (score 1):

you also might want to hit up [gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org/) they have an active community of moders.

super beginners can look [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6365702)