# Does anyone know how to create pretty + cool conky?

Tags: 11.10, conky

Does anyone know how to make pretty cool conky step by step?

Comment: Take a look at this - [Conky Guides/Links](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2281/conky-guides-links)

Answer (score 2):

"cool" is very subjective. I would start on the conky site, there are some sample configurations with screen shots

http://conky.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html

If you wish, there are a graphical tools to help with configuration

I like conkywizard

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/ConkyWizard?content=126352

[image: conky wizard]

There is also a conky gui on sourceforge

http://conkygui.sourceforge.net/pages/home

From there, conky is very flexible, sort of depends on what you want. You are going to have better luck if you as a more specific question about some specific feature you desire.