# Gnome shell with multi-device and multiple monitors

Tags: 11.10, gnome, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have two radeon 4850 HD with a crossfire link, with two monitors attached to each card. How do I configure xrandr to treat this as one big desktop? I've had all 4 monitors working with ximerama, but gnome-shell doesn't work under that.

If this is not currently possible, could I get a link to the relevant but reports?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't set that up, but maybe unchecking `/desktop/gnome/shell/windows/workspaces_only_on_primary` at `gconf-editor` helps. Have you tried that?

Comment: Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RolandiXor, Alexandre's comment is about setting the primary monitor and has nothing to do with running gnome-shell with multiple graphic cards, so the question still applies. From what research have done, it appears that none of the gnome developers have any interest in having gnome-shell working in the manner I would like.

Comment: And this looks to be working in 13.04 with gnome shell 3.6! I can finally use my third monitor!