# How do I install Conky?

Tags: conky

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conky Guides (links)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2281/conky-guides-links)

I have tried some tutorials but all to no avail of late. How do i correctly configure conky on ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865 for info

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways to do this but have you tried directly installing it from the `Software Center`? At least in Ubuntu 12.04 `conky` is there, not sure about 11.10 though.