# How do I customize Alt+Tab behaviour?

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, xfce, desktop-environments

**GOAL:**

I would like to make the little menu that pops up when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to gain the ability to jump to a particular window by pointing my mouse at one of the icons.  This is the behaviour that my Mac OSX laptop has.

**The Situation**

I use Xfce, with the default windows manager (XFwm).  I currently have Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.10, although I plan on updating both to XUbuntu 12.04 once the dust settles (probably mid-may?).  (Clarification, for my current setup, I installed Ubuntu, then added xfce manually after the fact).

So, a series of related questions.

How do I set this up?  (If this is not possible, please answer the following questions to help me learn)

Is the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> a function of the desktop environment, or the windows manager, or some other piece?  (IE if I switch to using some other tool, could I potentially get this)  Are there any customizations that are available either from settings or add-on applications that would allow me to change the behaviour of that menu?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Note to anyone who runs across this:  xfce 4.12 has this feature. :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be not what you are after, but if you are just after an alternative to alt tab I highly recommend super switcher.
I've used it for years and can't fault it.
Hope it helps.

Comment: What is super switcher?  Where can I find it: what's the package name?  (I did a search in synaptic, and didn't find anything with the name 'switcher')

Comment: here is the link
code.google.com/p/superswitcher/

don't worry that its a few years old. it just works.

Comment: Can you include a answer with instructions on how to do that? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

After that, just search for "CCSM" from the Dash and go to the Unity options.  It will have switcher options with customizable key configurations.

Comment: Xfce doesn't use Compiz, but Xfwm, meaning that ccsm won't do any good.